# Cannot route non-ascii URLs Flask

Tags: python, json, url, flask

I have a problem with the routing my URL adress to Flask, precisely with running it in web-browser. All I want is to transfer the sharp symbol "#" and some Russian words (as like "**#привет"** or "**#ПомогитеМнеПожалуйста**") together.

The screenshot of error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vzs2.jpg)

My programming code at the moment looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hashtags/<names>', methods=['GET'])
def get_hashtags(names):
    return jsonify({'Segmentation Hashtags': names})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9876)
```

So, basically, `<names>` is a parameter from function `get_hashtag` that is used for transfering my future hashtag to the web-browser using jsonify. I need to find the way of transfering any hashtag I want with sharp symbol "#" plus Russian letters. As far as I know, there is an ASCII-coding methods (something like .`**decode(utf-8)**`), but I have no idea how to use it properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The hashtags are causing the error. You can try to remove them on the client side, and just request this link instead:

`/hashtags/привет`

Hashtags in the url are often used to tell the browser which element on a page to jump to. For instance, on `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Technology`

the `#Technology` means jump to the technology section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try unidecode:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

@app.route('/hashtags/<names:string>', methods=['GET'])
def get_hashtags(names):
    return jsonify({'Segmentation Hashtags': unidecode(names)})
```